# Remove dictionaries in a list of dictionaries that matches a pattern using list comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries with text as value, and I want to remove the dictionaries that includes certain words in the texts.

```
df = [{'name':'jon','text':'the day is light'},{'name':'betty','text':'good night'},{'name':'shawn','text':'good afternoon'}]
```

I want to remove the dictionaries that include words 'light' and 'night' for 'text' key:

```
words = ['light','night']
pattern = re.compile(r"|".join(words))
```

Expected result:

```
df = [{'name':'shawn','text':'good afternoon'}]
```

Comment: If the pattern is intended to match only whole words but not partial words, "\b" should be used as the boundaries.

Answer (score 2):

```
[x for x in df if not any(w in x['text'] for w in words)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're close. All you need to do is write your list comprehension and apply the search pattern:

```
result = [x for x in df if not re.search(pattern, x['text'])]
```

Full example:

```
import re

df = [{'name':'jon','text':'the day is light'},{'name':'betty','text':'good night'},{'name':'shawn','text':'good afternoon'}]
words = ['light','night']
pattern = re.compile(r"|".join(words))
result = [x for x in df if not re.search(pattern, x['text'])]
print(result) # => [{'name': 'shawn', 'text': 'good afternoon'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer:

```
[x for x in df if not pattern.search(x['text'])]
```